# How to change cursor on plotly graph when mouse hover event occurred?

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly, legend

i'm trying to change cursor from pointer to default when hover event occurred on plotly's graph legend

```
   legend: {
          cursor: "default",
        x: xLegenda,
        y: yLegenda,
        orientation: "h",
        font: {
          size: 12,
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no property identified to apply css over displayed plotly graph but there's always a hack to apply on the displayed graph. Follow all the following steps to apply css on hover.

```
 Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
    
 dragLayer = document.getElementsByClassName('nsewdrag')[0];
```

nswedrag is a class applied on plotly rect element. fetch the element and apply  css on the graph.

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv')
myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
          dragLayer.style.cursor = 'pointer'
        });
```

remove class when graph points are not hovered.

```
 myPlot.on('plotly_unhover', function(data){
          dragLayer.style.cursor = ''
        });
```

you can also add additional functionality for relayout.

```
 myPlot.on('plotly_relayout', function(data){
          console.log("relayout DATA " , data);
        });
```

In Angular

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', this.data, this.layout);
        let dragLayer =<HTMLElement> document.getElementsByClassName('nsewdrag')[0];
        var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv')!

        myPlot.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
            // dragLayer["style"].cursor = 'pointer';
            dragLayer.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          })
          
        myPlot.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            // dragLayer["style"].cursor = '';
            dragLayer.style.cursor = '';

        })
```